# Wordpress plugin file accessing error

Tags: php, wordpress

While developing a wordpress plugin, I have created one `.php` file, and I'm defining a function there and then calling a function, if I am accessing that file in browser directly with as `server_url/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/file_name.php` then it is giving function redeclaration error at the line where I am calling that function. Please provide solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change function name in your plugin

Answer (score 0):

Probable the reason for that is there exists a same function with your plugin name in functions.php or there is a plugin with this name.
Try changing name of your plugin .
If that dosent workout then try changing your functiona name.

Comment: this is not the case with my function name

Comment: So what did you tried till now??